# I want to add all count data into a variable for other use. This my list, which have 2 object and contains 2 count in double format

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

This is my response, which is a list, I want to get a sum for **COUNT** like
**sum= 25016378.9+367583865.74=???** for future use. I am confused how to do it. I have created a model for the api parse and tried some way but not working

```
[
  {
    "MONTH": 6,
    "COUNT": 25016378.9
  },
  {
    "MONTH": 5,
    "COUNT": 367583865.74
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use method `fold()` : [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/fold.html)

```
List item = [
  {"MONTH": 6, "COUNT": 25016378.9},
  {"MONTH": 5, "COUNT": 367583865.74}
];

final result = item.fold<double>(
    0.0, (double prevVal, element) => prevVal + element["COUNT"]);

print(result);  // 392600244.64
```